# How can I use an unregistered package in Julia?

Tags: julia, package-managers

I want to use a package I found online, but I get the following error:

```
(Example) pkg> add Unregistered
  Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/General`
  Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git`
ERROR: The following package names could not be resolved:
 * Unregistered (not found in project, manifest or registry)
Please specify by known `name=uuid`.
```

I have seen others use the `add` command, but it does not seem to work in this case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To [add an unregistered package](https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1.2/managing-packages/#Adding-unregistered-packages-1), refer to it by URL:

```
(Example) pkg> add https://github.com/00vareladavid/Unregistered.jl
  Updating git-repo `https://github.com/00vareladavid/Unregistered.jl`
  Updating git-repo `https://github.com/00vareladavid/Unregistered.jl`
 Resolving package versions...
  Updating `~/.julia/environments/Example/Project.toml`
  [dcb67f36] + Unregistered v0.2.0 #master (https://github.com/00vareladavid/Unregistered.jl)
  Updating `~/.julia/environments/Example/Manifest.toml`
  [7876af07] + Example v0.5.3
  [dcb67f36] + Unregistered v0.2.0 #master (https://github.com/00vareladavid/Unregistered.jl)
```

Pkg will automatically install its dependencies.

After you have added the package, you can use it normally:

```
julia> import Unregistered
[ Info: Precompiling Unregistered [dcb67f36-efa0-11e8-0cef-2fc465ed98ae]
```

Note: Packages must have a toplevel `Project.toml` file with name, UUID, and version fields.

Comment: Also worth noting that you can `add` a local path, it doesn't just have to be a repo online (the note about needing a valid `Project.toml` still applies of course).

Comment: how do you install a specific version of an unregistered package?

Comment: when I try to add a local path, I am getting ERROR: `/home/.../AAA.jl` appears to be a local path, but directory does not exist. While the  `/home/.../AAA.jl` is a valid directory+file name.